# Механизм прочитывания сообщений в общем чате

Tags: chat

Есть общий чат, где могут общаться люди.

Есть таблица для чата:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat2help2`.`globalMessage` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` INT NOT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `message` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `fileId` INT NOT NULL,
  `time` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `date` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `status` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `siteId`, `userId`, `fileId`)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

есть поле status - индикатор того что сообщение прочитано. НО! оно актуально когда чат для двух человек. В данном же случае в чате может быть и 3 и 10 и смысл status теряется.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать что бы юзеру показывалось что у него есть непрочитанные из общего чата? 
запоминать дату последнего сообщения? какие еще варианты?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что нужна отдельная таблица с полями типа: id, id_user, id_message, status. Условно. Таким образом для каждого пользователя в эту таблицу будет добавляться запись, с тем сообщением, которое (по умолчанию) не прочитано. После чего изменять статус конкретной записи. Если все пользователи в общем чате прочитали сообщение, изменяем статус в вашей таблице.

Comment: В Телеграме это работает так, что если хотя бы один участник чата прочитал сообщение, оно считается прочитанным. Почему это вам не подходит?

Comment: Что входит в понятие "прочитано"? Хоть кем-то? текущим пользователем? Как фиксируется факт прочтения - оно выводилось на экран, пользователь пометил его прочтённым?

Comment: @iksuy почему тогда у меня отмечаются кол-во непрочитанных сообщений? а когда я пролистываю ленту то кол-во непрочитанных пропадает.

Comment: @Akina хоть кем-то прочитано это понятно как сделать. Для меня важен факт что бы человек видел сколько сообщений он не прочитал. Если я буду идти по принципу если хоть один прочитал то другие юзеры из чата не увидят что нового в нем появилось.

Comment: @YuriGo как вариант. Но мне кажется что грамоздкий получится

Comment: Тогда для ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ фиксируйте штамп времени прочтения (показа ему) чата (или последнего показанного ему сообщения этого чата) - все сообщения со штампом позже считайте непрочитанными (где бы он их прочитал, непоказанные-то?).

Comment: @Tsyklop Совсем нет) Тем более, если подумать, то вашу таблицу можно оптимизировать, т.е. все равно от разделения не уйти

Comment: @YuriGo тут беда в другом. Я не знаю точное кол-во участников чата, ограничений нет. что мне писать в другу таблицу? Вот допустим человек добавил сообщение - я должен во вторую таблицу добавить записи для всех участников чата, то бишь найти всех участников и добавить. Это все время.

Comment: @Akina имеете в виду сохранять на клиенте дату и время последнего сообщения и потом передавать при загрузке чата?

Comment: На клиенте-то зачем? Заведите под это дело табличку (ClientID, ChatID, LastViewTimestamp). При загрузке чата берёте для него последний штамп, считаете количество новых сообщений, выводите юзеру, а в таблице обновляете штамп на текущий.

Comment: @Tsyklop Вот смотрите, у вас каждый момент времени есть определенное количество пользователей в чате (предположим, они все постоянные и как в Вайбере, например). Есть таблица `messages` (id, title, desription) - можете еще поле придумать) В эту таблицу добавляются все записи из текущего чата. Создаем триггер на добавление новой записи, который в другую таблицу `notifications` (id, id_user, id_message, status) добавляет уведомление, которое должно/не должно быть прочитано. Все

Comment: @Akina понял. Если штампа нет то значит юзер не читал ничего.

Comment: Именно - если возвращается пустой набор записей, то все записи непрочитанные. Ну а обновление... создаём уникальный индекс по (ClientID, ChatID), делаем его с помощью `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (у Вас же MySQL, судя по бэктикам?) и не заморачиваемся. была запись или нет.